# FileNotFoundException occurred while upload the photo/video using xamarin forms android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, media, visual-studio-app-center, plugin.media.crossmedia

We are using xamarin essentials for camera permission. To capture photo/video we are using crossmedia nuget. After capture saved in local path then going to upload the photo/video. While upload the photo/video, I am getting below error in app center

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myproj/files/Movies/myproj/VIDEO_20200729_114115.mp4"
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Make sure that you had requested the read/write permission in the project .

Comment: Yes, Already read/write permission is there.

Comment: Did you get the same error message  on local ?